# Есть ли возможность повернуть любой элемент в xml при андроид верстке?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть ли возможность как либо повернуть именно рамку объекта, чтобы она не была перпендикулярна экрану?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е сделать так, чтобы повернулось не только содержимое контейнера TextView, но и сам контейнер(чтобы можно было привязать onClickListener)

Пытаюсь сделать радиальное меню. Ниже скрин прилагаю, готов выслушать советы по иному решению, если такое будет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В идеале чтобы "Touch зона" была исключительно как одна кнопка со второго скрина

P.S. android:rotate="X" не то - поворачивается только содержимое, а не сам контейнер

Comment: [CustomView](https://habr.com/ru/articles/727744/)

Comment: Я не уверен, что поможет, но можете попытаться поместить свой Text View в linear layout и повернуть его[linear layout]. OnClick соответственно на textView повесьте...